# SQL Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some difficulty with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(ArTrnDetail.NetSalesValue) AS [Price],
    'ExecuteSubReport(813, 0, Job)' AS [LaborCost],
    'ExecuteSubReport(815, 0, Job)' AS [MaterialCost],
    'ExecuteSymbolicMath(LaborCost + MaterialCost)' AS [TotalCost],
    'ExecuteSymbolicMath(Price - (LaborCost + MaterialCost))' AS [Margin],
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(ArTrnDetail.NetSalesValue) = 0 
            THEN 0
            ELSE 'ExecuteSymbolicMath(1 - (TotalCost / Price))'  <-- Where it's failing
    END AS [MarginPct]
```

The `ExecuteSubReport` and `ExecuteSymbolicMath` are company functions. The `ExecuteSymbolicMath` basically strips unwanted chars like $ and commas, does the math and returns the result as a string. The end result for the column being a decimal(2 places) between 0-1. When I try to run the query I get an error saying that it can't convert varchar to numeric. I've tried just about everything I can think of. I've tried replace, convert, cast, str.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hint: What's the type of the `CASE` expression? If it's numeric, how is `'ExecuteSymbolicMath(1-(TotalCost/Price))'` going to be treated as a numeric value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - You're a genius! I'll post the answer.

Comment: You are passing in strings, not functions.  I believe you want to remove the ' and ' around the expression you want SQL to parse as an expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SQL expression has exactly one type.  A `case` expression is no different.

According to the rules of SQL, numbers trump strings, so SQL tries to convert a string to a number -- and that is what is happening.

Just use `'0'` instead of `0` in the `case` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(ArTrnDetail.NetSalesValue) = 0 
      THEN '0'
      ELSE 'ExecuteSymbolicMath(1-(TotalCost/Price))'  <-- Where it's failing
  END) AS [MarginPct]
```

Or, if you actually want a calculation, get rid of all the single quotes:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(ArTrnDetail.NetSalesValue) = 0 
      THEN 0
      ELSE ExecuteSymbolicMath(1-(TotalCost/Price)) 
 END) AS [MarginPct]
```

Comment: I just came to this conclusion. This fixed my problem. I'll give you credit. Thank you all!